# Teradata format function

Tags: google-bigquery, teradata

I am converting query to teradata to Bigquery and I am trying to convert below query :

```
select 1234|| TRIM(CSUM(1,1)+ rowVal (FORMAT 'Z(17)9')) from schema.tableName
```

i am not able to get the meaning of (FORMAT 'Z(17)9') and I am trying to achive the same using below syntax:

```
select 1234|| ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod194*`;
```

How can I make sure that my big query result have (FORMAT 'Z(17)9')  this also and how can I add rowVal in row number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSUM` is legacy syntax (and `(1,1)` really inefficient). Your translation to ROW_NUMBER is correct, BigQuery's FORMAT is similar, should be:

```
select 1234|| FORMAT("%18d", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) + rowval)
```

If there's a `GROUP BY col` you must move it to `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: bigquery FORMAT  would work for you.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string